# LLVM crosscompiler for arm error

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I am trying to build LLVM in order to crosscompile for arm v7 on my laptop.

I am using the commands from http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html :

Download llvm, clang , then configure llvm with the following flags and then build.

.........................

**../llvm/configure -target armv7--eabi**

I am getting the following error. Any ideas what is wrong? Thank you

---

```
llvm[3]: ======= Finished Linking Debug+Asserts Unit test Utils
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Desktop/LLVM/llvm/arm_build/unittests/Transforms/Utils'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Desktop/LLVM/llvm/arm_build/unittests/Transforms'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Desktop/LLVM/llvm/arm_build/unittests'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/Desktop/LLVM/llvm/arm_build/projects'
Makefile:44: Makefile.config: No such file or directory
Makefile:151: /Makefile.rules: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/Makefile.rules'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Desktop/LLVM/llvm/arm_build/projects'
make: *** [all] Error 1
user@ubuntu:~/Desktop/LLVM/llvm/arm_build$ 
user@ubuntu:~/Desktop/LLVM/llvm/arm_build$  er.cpp for Debug+Asserts build
er.cpp for Debug+Asserts build
llvm[4]: Linking Debug+Asserts executable clang
er.cpp: command not found
user@ubuntu:~/Desktop/LLVM/llvm/arm_build$ llvm[4]: Linking Debug+Asserts executable clang
llvm[4]:: command not found
user@ubuntu:~/Desktop/LLVM/llvm/arm_build$ er.cpp for Debug+Asserts build
er.cpp: command not found
user@ubuntu:~/Desktop/LLVM/llvm/arm_build$ llvm[4]: Linking Debug+Asserts executable clang
llvm[4]:: command not found


----------
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crosscompile using llvm from desktop to arm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24204199/crosscompile-using-llvm-from-desktop-to-arm)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, this site is about correct LLVM compiler flags for arm. The other site is about which crosscompiler to use to crosscompile for arm.